# iOS redirect user to last accessed viewcontroller after authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, uiviewcontroller

My App has an authentication when you start it up, after you insert a pin, you will be authenticated to the start point of the app.

I want to add a log out after certain amount of inactivity, so let's say a user has navigated through the app and reached the settings page, and he didn't interact with it for 1 a min. I want to make the user go through the login process with the pin, however they will end up at last seen view controller, settings page in this example, and not end up at starting point controller

How can I go on about it ?

Cheers

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: Please read the question, that will just return to the beginning of the app, i want it go back to navigated page

Comment: i think something like that you want "[[AppDelegate window] setRootViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]];"